# Is it correct to say that $\lim_{x\to -\infty} e^x = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{e^x}$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function, parametric

I just see it logical...

Actually I think I can claim that

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} a^x = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{a^x}$$

$a$ being a parameter.

---

Is it correct?

Comment: You can do that.

Comment: Yes, it is. It is just a substitution: $\;y:=-x\;,\;\;x\to-\infty\iff y\to\infty\;$

Comment: You can put it as an answer and I'll accept it (Or should I *delete* the question?). What does $:=$ mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio ???

Comment: $:=$ means "is defined to be"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute:

$$y:=-x\;,\;\;\text{so that}\;\;x\to-\infty\iff y\to\infty\;,\;\;\text{and from here}:$$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} e^x=\lim_{y\to\infty} e^{-y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac1{e^y}=0$$